# TCP Connection in a Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, tcp

I've just set up my first TCP connection and I've used the program socket test to check to see if my code works. Which it does.

Now, what I'm trying to do is connect to a server that doesn't have an accessible IP address, but a dedicated web address instead.

For instance, my old code was this:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
        {
            client.Connect(ipAddress, 21);
            lblStatus.Text = "Connected...";
        }
    }
```

This happily works. Now I need it to connect to the following:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("server.myaddress.com");
        using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
        {
            client.Connect(ipAddress, 21);
            lblStatus.Text = "Connected...";
        }
    }
```

I've looked around to see what I should change IPAddress from but i cannot find anything. Alas, for my project I need to use the web address to connect to this server, so using an IP address isn't an option.

Can someone please show me what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var address = Dns.GetHostAddresses("server.myaddress.com")[0];
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(address);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But I've got complaints that address is already defined and that it cant convert the address in Parse to a string. Anyway way of fixing those?

Comment: @Sean The second line is unnecessary. `var address` should already be an `IPAddress`. See [GetHostAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, sorry. The second is really unnecessary. I wrote from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 public static void ConnectUs()
{       

        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry( "serveraddress.com");
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];

        using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
        {

        client.Connect(ipAddress, 21);
        client.SendTimeout = 3000;
        var status = client.Connected;
            Console.WriteLine(status);
        }
}
```